# GCE Instance [FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces

Tags: networking, linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to generate custom GCE image,
I've created a GCE image raw disk with this tool https://github.com/google/syzkaller/blob/master/tools/create-gce-image.sh

As you can see, the script gets as argument 2 parameters:

1. kernel image.
2. filesystem (generated by debootstrap)

I've generated the filesystem with debootstrap (just as described in the script) on a GCE instance:
Linux lab 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1+deb9u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

The kernel image is 4.19.134 x86_64_defconfig with these changes:
These are described here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/building-custom-os
And these:

```
CONFIG_KASAN=y
CONFIG_KASAN_INLINE=y
# CONFIG_KASAN_OUTLINE is not set
CONFIG_KCOV=y
CONFIG_KCOV_INSTRUMENT_ALL=y
CONFIG_KCOV_ENABLE_COMPARISONS=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y
CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS=y
CONFIG_SECURITYFS=y
# CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE is not set
CONFIG_BLK_NBD_DEV=y
```

While booting the machine (both in QEMU and as GCE instance), I see this error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Here is the full boot log https://pastebin.com/474AjKXe

When I'm running the disk.raw with QEMU, ssh works just fine.
But when I try to connect to the instance from a different instance, it's just does not work.
I can't even ping the machine (both to the external IP and to the internal one).

How can I point out what the problem is? is there anyway that I can connect to the instance itself for further debugging?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [connecting via the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console). In order to login you will need credentials so you can create a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to add them.

```
 #! /bin/bash
sudo useradd USERNAME; echo -e "PASSWORD\nPASSWORD" | passwd USERNAME | echo 'USERNAME ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

You can also try adding the following lines to your startup script as it appears your network service is not functioning correctly.

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```